# Can't call my association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Can any kind person look at this and see what is wrong with the code. I really must not withdraw my fields in the associative table! what is my problem?

view:

```
<% @playersname.each do |p|%> 
    <ul>
<li><%= p.name %></li>
<li><%= p.result.inspect  %></li>
</ul>
```

controller:

```
 class ResultsController < ApplicationController
def index
@playersname = Player.all
end
end
```

model:

```
  class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :result
end

 class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
   # attr_accessible :title, :body
   has_many :player
  end
```

migrations:

```
class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :players do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.references :results
  t.timestamps
  end
end
end

class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :results do |t|
    t.string "result", :limit => 40
    t.string "cal", :limit => 40
    t.string "sum",:limit => 300
  t.timestamps
 end
end
end
```

Comment: How do you know something is wrong?  What error/unexpected result are you getting when you try to load the view?

Comment: my problem is with .inspect so says nil. but there have a id

Comment: if I put results_id then I get a number. if I put result.inspect then I get nil

Comment: So what are you trying to do with the line p.results.inspect?  What are you hoping the output will be?

Comment: Downvoted due to OPs unwillingness to do any of the work himself.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pluralize player, here in your code:

```
   has_many :player
```

should be

```
   has_many :players
```

Also, in your view you should change:

```
<li><%= p.result.inspect  %></li>
```

to something else.  It won't work because a) there is no "result" method for `p` there is only a `results` method for it.  And when you call .inspect on `results` you will get something you probably don't want to send to the browser.

Once you get the association figured out, you probably want something like the following in your view:

```
<h1>Results</h1>
<%= render :partial => "result", :collection => @results %>
```

and then you will create a partial in your views folder named `_result.rb` and containing code like this

```
<h3>Result: <%= result.title %></h3>
<p><%= result.body %></p>
```

Comment: i have no problem with set players. but i have problem call result.
do you understand me?

Comment: I get this result: undefined method `results' for # <Player:0x43d2d70>

Comment: Right.  That's because each result has many players, but players do not have many results.  If you expect each player to have many results, you will need to add that declaration to the player model:  'has_many :results' and add a corresponding 'belongs_to :player' to your results model.  Of course, ou will also want to remove the declarations you currently have ('has many :player' and 'belongs_to' result)

Comment: i change with you say. no i get this error : SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: results.player_id: SELECT "results".* FROM "results"  WHERE "results"."player_id" = 1

Comment: Yes, when you add those declarations you will need to add a player_id field to your results table.  You will need a migration to do that.  Here is the help you need for that:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method

Comment: i must create many-to-many migrations?

Comment: I don't know.  Do you have a many-to-many relationship?  Can a player have multiple results?  Can a result have multiple players?  If yes to both of those last two, then yes, you have a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: but it is not they, if you want to put "player_id" on the other side as well?

Comment: I explained how to decide if you need a many-to-many relationship, above.  If you need to learn how to implement a many-to-many relationship you should check out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: @Max We're not going to be able to write all of your code for you.  You need to read up on ActiveRecord relations and Migrations.  When you have another specific question, you can ask another specific question.  Meanwhile, please upvote or accept my answer, because it correctly answers your question "What is wrong with my code."

Comment: is not answer of my questions. i know i noob in rails. do not solve problems. so help me!